# JSF rendered fill gap

Tags: jsf-2

when jsf doesn't render component, how to fill the gap where component were supposed to place. Component just disappeared and other component does fill the it's space. I just need to leave its space empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a panel and place your component inside the panel. Give the panel the proper height and width. So that the space remains filled by the panel even if the component inside is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If the rendering doesn't contain sensitive user-specific information like admin buttons (it likely doesn't otherwise this question makes little sense), you can also just make use of CSS `visibility` property instead.

```
<h:someComponent ... styleClass="#{bean.show ? '' : 'invisible'}" />
```

with

```css
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This way it will still render the output and occupy the desired space, but remain invisible (which is by the way the difference with the well known `display: none` which doesn't occupy the space at all). Note that this way it also enables toggling the visibility entirely clientside by JavaScript.